Nuget Package include runtimeconfig
I have a Dotnet exe application (App1) which I am trying to create a nuget package.
This package is used in another application(App2) which includes the above Nuget Package and invokes its dll's. This applicaiton is run in  a docker linux container.
When Creating the Nuget Package for App1 I am trying to include the deps.json and runtimeconfig.json file in the .nuspec file. I am including these files as it is required in the container to run
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Release\net6.0\abc.net.dll" target="lib\net6.0" /> 
     <file src="bin\Release\net6.0\asdfsd.net.dll" target="lib\net6.0" /> 
     <file src="bin\Release\net6.0\derty.net.dll" target="lib\net6.0" /> 
     <file src="bin\Release\net6.0\eredsww.net.dll" target="lib\net6.0" /> 
    
     <file src="bin\Release\net6.0\app.net.deps.json" target="contentFiles/any/any" />
     <file src="bin\Release\net6.0\app.net.runtimeconfig.json" target="contentFiles/any/any" />
  </files>
</package>

The consuming application fails when doing a build because of the content files.
What is the correct way to include deps.jsong and runtimeconfig json to the consuming applicaitons
